# Coefficients of the power of a sum of fermionic operators?

Tags: fermions, grassmann-numbers

Consider the sum of $N$ fermionic operators $f_1+f_2+\cdots+f_N$, where the $f$‘s anti-commute, i.e. $\{f_i,f_j\}=0$.

**What is the expression for $(f_1+f_2+\cdots+f_N)^N$?**

Would the $f$’s be normal variables, the power of the sum would be given by the multinomial coefficients (a generalised version of the binomial coefficients). For the fermionic case the situation has to be much simpler as the terms commute, and since there are $N$ variables and it is the power of $N$, only a term proportional to $f_1f_2\cdots f_N$ survives (as you can always anti-commute the surviving terms to $f_1 f_2\cdots f_N$).  My naive guess is that by symmetry, it is proportional to $\pm1$ or $0$ but I’m not sure.

**What about for $(f_1+f_2+\cdots f_N)^M$ with $M\leq N$**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider
$$
\left(f_1 + f_2 + ... + f_N\right)^2 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^N f_i\right)^2=
\sum_{i, j=1}^N f_if_j =\\
\sum_{i, j<i} f_if_j + \sum_{j, i<j}f_if_j + \sum_i f_i^2 = \sum_{i, j<i} (f_if_j+f_jf_i)=0
$$
Hence, for $M\geq 2$
$$
\left(f_1 + f_2 + ... + f_N\right)^M =0
$$

**Corollary**
$$
e^{\alpha\left(f_1 + f_2 + ... + f_N\right)} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\alpha^n}{n!}\left(f_1 + f_2 + ... + f_N\right)^n =
1 + \alpha \left(f_1 + f_2 + ... + f_N\right)
$$
This formula happens a lot in discussions of fermionic coherent states and/or grassman numbers.

Comment: it is also zero for N=1, right?

Comment: @flippiefanus for $M=1$ it is $f_1 + f_2 + ... + f_N$ (I corrected a typo, for $M=N=1$ it is simply $f_1$)

Comment: I’m quite puzzled... this doubt came up because I was considering a product of fermionic operators $c_1 c_2 \cdots$ which in turn my be expressed as $c_i = \sum_n^N a_i^n d_n$, with $d_n$ fermionic as well. Does this mean that in general, products of this type are zero provided the operators $c_i$ admit some $c_i = \sum_n^N a_i^n d_n$?

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian You seem to be neglecting the ordering of the operators when using the multinomial expansion. Try calculating explicitly $(f_1+f_2)^2=f_1^2+f_1f_2 + f_2f_1 + f_2^2$ and $(f_1+f_2+f_3)^2$

Comment: I don’t quite understand your last comment. However, I can expand on my previous comment: $$c_1 c_2 \cdots =(\sum_n a^n_1 d_n)(\sum_k a^k_2 d_k) \cdots = (\sum_{nk} a^n_1 a^k_2 d_n d_k) \cdots = ( \sum_{n>k} a^n_1 a^k_2 d_n d_k +\sum_{n<k} a^n_1 a^k_2 d_n d_k + \sum_n a^n_1 a^n_2 d_n d_n) \cdots = (\sum_{n>k} a^n_1 a^k_2 d_n d_k - \sum_{n<k} a^n_1 a^k_2 d_k d_n)\cdots = (\sum_{n>k} a^n_1 a^k_2 d_n d_k - \sum_{k<n} a^k_1 a^n_2 d_n d_k)\cdots \neq 0$$ So you are right and I asked the wrong question... What I wanted to compute was $$c_1 c_2 \cdots =(\sum_n a^n_1 d_n)(\sum_k a^k_2 d_k) \cdots$$

Comment: Insead of changing the order of operators you can exchange the dummy indices n and k, so that you combine the two sums

Comment: @Vadim But it doesn’t cancel out no? One is left with $c_1c_2\cdots =( \sum_{n>m}( a^n_1 a^k_2 -a^k_1 a^n_2)d_nd_k) \cdots $. This is going to become really complicated in the general case, specially for $N\geq M$.

Comment: No, in general case it doesn't cancel out. In the case written in the OP you had $a_1^n=a_2^k=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Linear combination of fermionic operators are again fermionic operators. Thus, they do what any fermionic operator does: They square to zero.

Comment: Hi @NorbertSchuch, do you know what happens in a general product? i.e. $(\sum_n a_n c_n) (\sum_m b_m c_m) \cdots$ with $a_n\neq b_n \neq \cdots$? I am guessing it will have a general form of $\sum_{i<j<k<\cdots} A_{i,j,k,\cdots} c_ic_jc_k \cdots$ for some $A$?

Comment: Why do you want to consider that?

Comment: For instance when you have a product of fermionic operators $c_1c_2\cdots$ that in turn my be expressed individually as $c_i=\sum_n \phi^n_i d_n$ for some new fermionic operators $d_n$, transforming $c_1 c_2 \cdots$ into $(\sum_n \phi^n_1 d_n)(\sum_m \phi^m_2 d_m)\cdots$. I find the later useful as the $d$’s diagonalise $H$ and thus create and annihilate eigenstates.

Comment: Sure, but in that case the $\phi_k^\ell$ are *very special*: They form an orthogonal matrix! In that case, these formulas have *much more structure*. Asking about such kind of expressions (with orthogonal $\phi$) makes sense. Asking for such expression with non-orthogonal $\phi$ seems somewhat contrived and not really useful - that's why I was asking.

Comment: so when the $\phi$’s are orthogonal one can simplify $(\sum_n \phi^n_1 d_n)(\sum_m \phi^m_2 d_m)\cdots$? It looks a bit like $(U_1 v)(U_2 v)\cdots$ but I dont know how to go further.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to simplify it in the language of the original d's, rather than using that the c's form a nice basis. But if the phi are orthogonal, the c's are separate fermionic modes, so products of separate c's are again states with the same # of fermions.